# Spark Streaming: Store processed data into elasticsearch

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch, streaming

I have an exercise that implementing a service which fetch data from Kafka, process it and store the result into elasticsearch using Spark Streaming.

I can ingest data from Kafka to my service and process it in a Spark cluster but I don't know how to persist the result into elasticsearch in an action. As of now, my code look like this:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()...

JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));
...
JavaPairInputDStream<String, Event> eventStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(...);
eventStream.foreachRDD( rdd -> {
    rdd.foreach(Application::processEvent);
});
```

The method processEvent look like:

```
public static void processEvent(Tuple2<String, Event> t) {
    //Process event t here
    ...
    // here I want to persist the result into elasticsearch
}
```

I'm new with Apache Spark. Please tell me how can I persist the result into elasticsearch after process the event.
Note that I know how to index a document into elasticsearch in a standalone java application, I just don't know how to use it with Spark Streaming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide elastic configurations and call `saveToEs()` to save data from Spark RDD to Elastic Search Index.

The following is the *scala* code that you can take as a reference and you can implement the same in Java

I have the following dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11" % "5.0.0"
```

Then code goes like below:

```
// Create SparkConf object with Elastic details

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Job Name")
sparkConf.set("es.nodes", "Elastic_IP_1, Elastic_IP_2")
sparkConf.set("es.port", "9200")
sparkConf.set("es.batch.size.entries", "1000")
sparkConf.set("es.batch.size.bytes", "102400")

// Create SparkSession using the above SparkConf

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()

...
...
...

val myRDD = ......

var elasticConfig = new HashMap[String, String]
elasticConfig += ("es.mapping.date.detection" -> "false")
elasticConfig += ("es.mapping.date.rich" -> "false")

import org.elasticsearch.spark._

// Save rdd to elastic search index
myRDD.saveToEs("indexName", elasticConfig)
```

Comment: @Khode I've already opened a Streaming Context for getting data from Kafka, so now can I open another context for working with elasticsearch?

Comment: you don't have to create one more context, just add these configurations to the existing one, the above is an example for batch execution, make necessary changes wrt streaming...